# Which one is the right sentence?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, word-order

If you don't know about Indian independence movements and partition history. Sorry we can't be friends.
Or 
If you don't know Indian independence movements and partition history. Sorry we can't be friends.

Comment: I cannot help thinking that some of the close/down votes are due to the attitude expressed in the example sentences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are incorrect, because the first sentence is not able to stand alone. You must join it to the next one with a comma. It does not express a complete idea because it doesn't include the conclusion. Without the first sentence, the idea in the second sentence has no justification as well.

But the difference between them, the inclusion or exclusion of 'about', doesn't matter and both read passably. The first is the most straightforward, as you must know 'about' a subject (independence movements), and so it's more correct. The second sentence implies that this is the relationship between the movements and you anyway; the second is therefore more colloquial.